# How to clear input values of dynamic form in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a dynamic form as a functional component which is generated via a class based component. I want to make reset button which clears the input field values and sets the state to null array.

Full code is available here: 
https://codesandbox.io/s/beautiful-archimedes-o1ygt

I want to make a reset button, clearing all the input values and initializing the Itemvalues array to null.
Even if I set the values to null, it doesn't clear the input field.

However, the problem I'm facing is that since, it is a dynamic form and a functional component it doesn't have a predefined state for each individual form field making it difficult to set value to null.
Can  someone please help, I'm stuck on this from a long time

Comment: Do you want to keep the fields but reset the value ? How the objects inside the `Items` array looks like ?

Comment: Your code is unreadable and got syntax errors, fix it.

Comment: How are the items generated to begin with?

Comment: In the sample code, I've generated them manually, but in the actual code the array is filled from API

Comment: @user8306074 gotcha, working on something for you.

Comment: Thanks! I've been stuck on this for so long :/

Comment: @user8306074 sweet see my solution below with the sandbox.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's a codesandbox to show you how to reset the items: https://codesandbox.io/s/romantic-heisenberg-93qi7

I also left a note for you on how to get this to work with your API data, see the comment inside `onChangeText()`

The problem is that the inputs are not controlled by state as you have deduced. We should create an updated object for each item from your API, giving it a `value` prop.

### index.js

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import Cart from "./Cart";

import "./styles.css";

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      Items: [],
      itemvalues: [{}]
    };
    this.onChangeText = this.onChangeText.bind(this);
    this.getItems = this.getItems.bind(this);
    this.handleReset = this.handleReset.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    this.findFieldIndex = this.findFieldIndex.bind(this);
    this.trimText = this.trimText.bind(this);
  }

  getItems = () => {
    /*if the data is coming from an API, store it in an array then .map() over it.
     we can add a value prop to the object like:
      so you can do something like:

      const newItems = [...apiData].map((item) => {
        return {
          ...item,
          value: ""
        }
      })

      this.setState({
        Items: newItems
      })
     */

    this.setState({
      Items: [
        {
          name: "item1",
          description: "item1",
          group: "groupA",
          dtype: "str",
          value: ""
        },
        {
          name: "item2",
          description: "item2",
          group: "groupA",
          dtype: "str",
          value: ""
        },
        {
          name: "item3",
          description: "item3",
          group: "groupB",
          dtype: "str",
          value: ""
        },
        {
          name: "item4",
          description: "item4",
          group: "groupB",
          dtype: "str",
          value: ""
        }
      ]
    });
  };

  onChangeText = e => {
    const updatedItems = [...this.state.Items].map(item => {
      if (item.name === e.target.name) {
        return {
          ...item,
          value: e.target.value
        };
      } else {
        return item;
      }
    });

    const updatedItemValues = [...updatedItems].reduce((obj, curr) => {
      if (!obj[curr.group]) {
        obj[curr.group] = [];
      }
      obj[curr.group] = [...obj[curr.group], { [curr.name]: curr.value }];
      return obj;
    }, {});

    this.setState({
      ...this.state,
      Items: updatedItems,
      itemvalues: updatedItemValues
    });
  };

  findFieldIndex = (array, name) => {
    return array.findIndex(item => item[name] !== undefined);
  };
  trimText(str) {
    return str.trim();
  }

  handleReset = () => {
    const resetedItems = [...this.state.Items].map(item => {
      return {
        ...item,
        value: ""
      };
    });

    this.setState(
      {
        ...this.state,
        Items: resetedItems,
        itemvalues: []
      },
      () => console.log(this.state)
    );
  };

  handleSubmit = () => {
    console.log(this.state.itemvalues);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {
          <Cart
            Items={this.state.Items}
            getItems={this.getItems}
            handleSubmit={this.handleSubmit}
            handleReset={this.handleReset}
            onChangeText={this.onChangeText}
          />
        }
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

### Cart.js

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import Form from "./Form";

const Cart = props => {
  useEffect(() => {
    props.getItems(props.Items);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <Form Items={props.Items} onChangeText={props.onChangeText} />

      <button onClick={props.handleSubmit}>Submit</button>
      <button onClick={props.handleReset}>Reset</button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Cart;
```

The Cart component can remain mostly the same, we do not need to pass in `props.items` to `useEffect()` dependency.

### Form.js

```
import React from "react";

const Form = props => {
  return (
    <div>
      {props.Items.map(item => {
        return (
          <input
            name={item.name}
            placeholder={item.description}
            data-type={item.dtype}
            data-group={item.group}
            onChange={e => props.onChangeText(e)}
            value={item.value}
          />
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
};
export default Form;
```

Now in `Form` component, we provide each input a value prop that is connected to the item our upper-most parent component-state.

That's pretty much all you need to reset the values.

Comment: When I do this, then it is not allowing me to make any changes to the input field values. So, the value doesn't change at all.

Comment: @user8306074 that's very strange, I've only made additions to the code you provided in the sandbox. In the sandbox I provided to you, is the feature not performing as you expected? Possibly there's more to your code that we dont see?

Comment: Yea, there is more to it but that's a separate component not affecting this one. I saw the state values but the onChangeText function doesn't update the value in Items array. Let me check if I have copied the values correctly or not.

Comment: And if I use this logic so I dont need itemvalues array ?

Comment: @user8306074 cool. I found some weird bugs with the itemsvalues array so I commented out . I'm not sure what you're using it for, but I can help you reconstruct it. For now though, this logic is just for updating the inputs and resetting them.

Comment: This logic seems better than what I was trying, before but I'm not sure why it is not working, it is not allowing me to type into the input field.

Comment: @user8306074 Hmm, I think the only reason why that would not work is if there's some discrepancy with the `onChange()` handler. If you want you can join me in this live code-share room. https://codeshare.io/UbKVU

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195556/discussion-between-christopher-ngo-and-user8306074).

Answer (score 3):

See if that works for you:

**[Working example on CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/dynamicformresetsoanswer-ltoxg)**

[image]

Since you were already using hooks in part of your code, I've converted your class into a functional component using hooks **(my advice: learn hooks and forget about class components).**

I've added a `value` property to your `INITIAL_STATE` so it will keep the input value for each `inputItem`.

**Full CODE:**

**index.js**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import FormV2 from "./FormV2";

import "./styles.css";

function App() {
  const INITIAL_STATE = [
    {
      name: "item1",
      description: "item1",
      group: "groupA",
      dtype: "str",
      value: "" // ADDED VALUE PROPERTY TO KEEP THE INPUT VALUE
    },
    {
      name: "item2",
      description: "item2",
      group: "groupA",
      dtype: "str",
      value: ""
    },
    {
      name: "item3",
      description: "item3",
      group: "groupB",
      dtype: "str",
      value: ""
    },
    {
      name: "item4",
      description: "item4",
      group: "groupB",
      dtype: "str",
      value: ""
    }
  ];

  const [inputItems, setInputItems] = useState(INITIAL_STATE);

  function handleChange(event, index) {
    const newValue = event.target.value;
    setInputItems(prevState => {
      const aux = Array.from(prevState);
      aux[index].value = newValue;
      return aux;
    });
  }

  function handleReset() {
    console.log("Reseting Form to INITIAL_STATE ...");
    setInputItems(INITIAL_STATE);
  }

  function handleSubmit() {
    inputItems.forEach(item =>
      console.log(
        "I will submit input: " + item.name + ", which value is: " + item.value
      )
    );
  }

  return (
    <FormV2
      handleSubmit={handleSubmit}
      handleReset={handleReset}
      handleChange={handleChange}
      inputItems={inputItems}
    />
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

**FormV2.js**

```
import React from "react";

function FormV2(props) {
  const formInputItems = props.inputItems.map((item, index) => (
    <div key={item.name}>
      {item.name + ": "}
      <input
        type="text"
        data-type={item.dtype}
        data-group={item.group}
        placeholder={item.description}
        value={item.value}
        onChange={event => props.handleChange(event, index)}
      />
    </div>
  ));

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <form>{formInputItems}</form>
      <button onClick={props.handleSubmit}>Submit</button>
      <button onClick={props.handleReset}>Reset</button>
      <div>State: {JSON.stringify(props.inputItems)}</div>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

export default FormV2;
```

Answer (score 2):

In order to control the values of the child components (Items) which I presume are input fields you need to be passing down their values from their parent component. So each of your items will have an `item.value` which is stored in the parent component's state.

That means that in the parent component you will be able to define a method which clears all of the item values it is storing in its state.
That will probably look something like

```
resetInputs = () => {
    this.setState({
        inputFields: this.state.inputFields.map(inputField => {
            ...inputField,
            value: ''
        }
    })
}
```

Also you'll need to write what kind of tag you want for your code to work, like input.

So what you'll end up with for the code of the child component you shared is something like:

```
const Form = (props) => {
    return (
    <div>
        {props.Items.map(item => (
          <input
            name={item.name}
            value={item.value}
            placeholder={item.description}
            onChange={e => props.onChangeText(e)}
          /> 
        )
        )}
      </div> 
    );
}
export default Form
```

Comment: Can you tell me how should I set the state in parent component in this case ?

Comment: Do you mean when you change a value in the input field? Because it doesn't look like you defined onChangeText anywhere.

Comment: your onChangeText would need to be something like this: ```onChangeText = (itemIndex, newValue) => { this.setState({ Items: [...this.state.Items.slice(0, itemIndex), { ...this.state.Items[itemIndex], value: newValue }, ...this.state.Items.slice(itemIndex + 1) ] }```

Comment: and then in the child component you would use it like this: ```{props.Items.map((item, index) => ( <input ........ onChange={e => props.onChangeText(index, e.currentTarget.value)}```

Comment: In my case, I have a function which populates the Items array and for each Item an input field is generated. So, I dont know how to access those values. I'm saving the input values entered by the user as an array in class based components(parent component)

Comment: Didn't you write the function which populates the Items array? Besides, once you've used it to populate the state of the parent component, you can access that state with this.state in that component (which you already do, and index into that array of items to get or set (via setState) whatever you need from them.

Comment: I tried setting the values of that state to a null array, it updates the state but doesnt clear the input fields.

Comment: Have you added `value={item.value}` to your inputs?

Comment: Also, you need to set the value of each one to empty string `''` individually, like in the onChangeText from my comment above. Nullifying the whole array will make you lose control of the values of the input fields, so you won't be able to change them.

Comment: Hi, Can you have a look at the updated question and let me know how and should I use `value={item.value}`

Answer (score 2):

You want to manage the state of unknown number `N` of items, one way to achieve it is by managing a single object which contains all states, for example, `setValuesManager` manages `N` inputs and clicking the `button` reset its state:

```js
function TextAreaManager() {
  const [valuesManager, setValuesManager] = useState([...items]);
  return (
    <Flexbox>
      {valuesManager.map((value, i) => (
        <TextBoxItem
          key={i}
          value={value}
          onChange={e => {
            valuesManager[i] = e.target.value;
            setValuesManager([...valuesManager]);
          }}
        />
      ))}
      <PinkButton
        onClick={() =>
          setValuesManager([...Array(valuesManager.length).fill('')])
        }
      >
        Reset All
      </PinkButton>
    </Flexbox>
  );
}
```

Demo:

[image: Edit OS Q 556724228 - Manage dynamic form state]

Comment: So, the problem is that, I don't have fixed values for items. In my case, I have a function which populates the Items array and for each Item an input field is generated. So, I dont know how to access those values. I'm saving the input values as an array in class based components

Comment: You can add as many items you want, as I mentioned `state of unknown number N of items`, this is roughly the idea of how you need to solve your problem.

Comment: Okay let me try this.

Comment: I tried this, but the reset button doesnt seem to work, it doesnt clear the input fields

Comment: Did you check the demo? https://codesandbox.io/s/os-q-56622204-jslwy?fontsize=14, you got a problem with your code. And as mentioned in comments, fix your question your code is unreadable

Comment: Hi, can you please have a look at the updated question